# android help me to get the monthly notification ..what condition should be given for months having days 30,31,28

Tags: android

Here is my code..In this code, I set the notification for months having 30 days..how to give the condition and set the notification for months having 31,28 days.Here I gave the condition INTERVEL_DAY*30 for months having 30 days..Help me to set the notification for all months and what condition should be given

```
    intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), RQS_1, intent, 0);
    alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
    cale.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY*30, pendingIntent);
    alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    intent = new Intent("android.media.action.DISPLAY_NOTIFICATION");
    broadcast = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 100, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cale.getTimeInMillis(), broadcast);
```

Comment: Setting 3 alarm will do the trick. One is for 30s, second is for 31, and other is for feb.

Comment: I would rather suggest you do not aim for a single interval setting, rather set the next alarm month-per-month

Comment: Hey...thank u But i need  the solution like..if i select the date and if i gave notification should be monthly for eg.every month 29...how should i give the condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.DATE,1);
calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH,1);//1 Means February
calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR,2017);

calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

hope this helps.Comment if you have any doubt.

Answer (score 0):

Take year, month, date. From there you can get the last day of this month. Put this date like this AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY*LastDayofMonth.

Answer (score 0):

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault());
calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)

AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY*30 -> AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
```

Answer (score -1):

Use a Calendar object.  Calendar has an add function where you can add minuted, days, months, etc.  Add 1 month to the current date, and it will be 1 month from today.  Then convert it to milliseconds since epoch for AlarmManager.

Comment: He IS using calendar. Furthermore he is looking for a way to set it once with repeat interval

Comment: I missed him using it in there, my bad.  As for wanting to do it once with setRepeating-  you can't.  Set a 1 time alarm, and have that alarm set the next.

Comment: thank u...if i set the notification option to monthly....if i use calender object andd add function can i get the notification correctly ?

Comment: Hey...thank u But i need the solution like..if i select the date and if i gave notification should be monthly for eg.every month 29...how should i give the condition